# Jmeter LDAP issue

Tags: ssl, jmeter, ldap

I am testing LDAP server . When i enabled the Secured LDAP , I am facing below error can anyone tell me how to resole this
Java NoSuchAlgorithmException - SunJSSE, sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext
When I enable TrustAll Certificates box in higher version of Jmeter I am not facing the issue. But I am not able to achieve the throughput. Can anyone tell me if it is the Jmter TrustAll Certificates option that is causing the throughput issue.

I Tried now. I am expecting successful bind

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using Java 8 you can try [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce-all-downloads.html)
2. You can try upgrading [Java](https://openjdk.org/) to the latest version
3. If you cannot reach target throughput using a single JMeter instance you can consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: I upgraded Java to 17 & tried still facing same error. Not sure what is the issue. i am creating keystore of crt file & added it to system.properties file of Jmeter & tried . But did not help. My system.properties look like this

Comment: # Keystore properties (client certificates)
# Location
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=D:\Software\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\mykeystore1.jks
#
#The password to your keystore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changethis
#
#javax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider
#javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType [default = KeyStore.getDefaultType()]